# Greens function application Abrikosov - QFT in Statistial Physics

Tags: greens-functions

I am looking at section 7 of the textbook mentioned in the title, and he defines the G as
$$G\equiv -i\langle T \psi_a(x)\psi_b(x')\rangle$$
Then says that we can construct j from this as
$$j=\pm\frac{1}{2m} \lim_{r\rightarrow r'}\lim_{t'\rightarrow t+0}(\nabla_r-\nabla_{r'})G_{aa}(x,x')$$
I do not see why this is (and why it isnt zero in the limit).  j($/i\hbar)$ is $\psi\nabla\psi^\dagger-\psi^\dagger\nabla\psi$so if I take $\nabla_rG$ i have (the limit ensures that we are time ordered)
$$\nabla_rG = \lim_{t'\rightarrow t+0} \frac{\hbar}{2m}\nabla_r\langle\psi(x)\psi(x')\rangle$$
My confusion is that since we have r, it will only act on $\psi$ and  Iwill not recover what I expect to.  IS this why the r limit must appear?  And then in this case, where does the $\nabla_{r'}$ arise?